# Python 3.3 list index out of range ERROR

Tags: python, encryption

My  task was to encrypt a random message using a list of 7,3,19,5. Here is my code for this task:

```
def k():
    m=input ("Please enter a message: ")
    x=""
    w = [7,3,19,5]
    g=0
    for ch in m:
        en = chr(ord(ch)+ w[g])#encryption
        x = (x+en)#adding
        print(str(x))#output
        g=g+1
k()
```

My output is this:

```
Please enter a message: hello world
o
oh
oh
ohq
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
 k()
File "H:\t2test.py", line 7, in k
   en = chr(ord(ch)+ w[g])#encryption
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: See what happens if g is incremented 4 times. What would w[4] be?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to solve right now but i have to reuse the list until the encryption is completed. For example my message is :Computer and my list is [7,3,19,5]  so this is how it should go: c + 7, o +3, m + 19, p + 5 and it repeats the encryption with the rest of the letters until the encryption is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your list if you know about the modulo operator `%` (division remainder).

You also don't need to keep count manually (there's [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for that), and you should be using better variable names:

```
def encrypt():
    message = input("Please enter a message: ")
    encrypted = ""
    offsets = [7,3,19,5]
    lenoff = len(offsets)
    for index, char in enumerate(message):
        encrypted += chr(ord(char)+ offsets[index % lenoff]) #encryption
        print(encrypted)
```

Comment: @professor  random numbers would be  more useful i guess

Comment: Well, that's unrelated to the OP's question. Apart from that, why should the range of random numbers be constrained to the length of the message?

Comment: yes sir..that's not necessary but just a quick fix for OP's code..but your ans is the better one

Answer (score 0):

The length of string is variable and list has got fixed elements.So modify your list.

Modify your list `w = [7,3,19,5]*len(m)`

```
def k():
    m=input ("Please enter a message: ")
    x=""
    w = [7,3,19,5]*len(m)
    g=0
    for ch in m:

        en = chr(ord(ch)+ w[g])#encryption
        x = (x+en)#adding
        print(str(x))#output
        g=g+1
k()
```

output:

```
Please enter a message: hello world
o
oh
oh
ohq
ohqv
ohqv#
ohqv#
ohqv#t
ohqv#ty
ohqv#tyo
ohqv#tyow
```

Instead you can use random numbers.

For the above function you can import random

```
w=[]
for i in range(len(m)):
    w.append(random.randrange(len(m)))
```

Comment: @ChipZ If this worked Consider accepting this as answer

Comment: Why would you need a list of length 44 to encrypt a message with 11 characters? Especially since there's no need to elongate the list at all.

Answer (score 0):

resetting the g value when it reaches the length of w will also work.

```
def k():
m=input("Please enter a message: ")
x=""
w = [7,3,19,5]
g=0
for ch in m:
    en = chr(ord(ch)+ w[g])#encryption
    x = (x+en)#adding
    print(str(x))#output
    g=g+1
    if (g==len(w)):
        g=0
k()
```